# How to properly import a javascript file/function API to a React.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Hey Stackoverflow :) Long time reader, first time poster. To the point:

I'm fairly new to web programming (done much more C# and game programming). I've been given a task that requires me to write a simple React.js app. I am to use an included api.min.js javascript file that includes an "API", that is supposed to sort of mimic a server, has a set of built in functions to fetch data ('/getitem', '/getusers', '/putitem', etc), and mimics lost requests now and then. The API code has been minified and is one single line of some 4500 characters, and sadly i don't think i can include all the code from this file, since it's not mine (and, well it's 4500 chars :P). But some clues: when beautified it starts off like this:

```
var api = function() {
  function t(t) {
    for (var e = t.length - 1; e > 0; e--) {
      var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (e + 1)),
        r = t[e];
      t[e] = t[n], t[n] = r
    }
    return t
    etc...
```

And ends like this:

```
              etc...
              },
              setRequestHeaders: function(t, e) {
                if ("number" != typeof t && "string" != typeof t && "number" != typeof e && "string" != typeof e) throw new Error("Arguments both header and value must be numbers or strings");
                l[t] = e
              }
            };
          return m
        };
      return {
        XMLHttpRequest: y
      }
    }();
```

One of the examples included in the file looks like this:

```
// Example 1:
var x = api.XMLHttpRequest();
x.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log(x.readyState, x.status, x.responseText);
};
x.open("GET", "/getusers");
x.send();
```

If i paste the API line and the example code into say, jsfiddle.net, it works fine and gives me the data in a format i would know how to use. But i can't seem to get it to work in my React-project in VScode. Whenever i try to import the file, i get errors of the type

```
Line 6:7:     Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

That would be the line:

```
t[e] = t[n], t[n] = r
```

... from the first code example above.

So I'm a bit clueless as to how to proceed atm... Does anyone have any suggestions on how i could include this API in my VScode React.js project and access the functions from the api.min.js file? I feel like there probably is some really simple solution to this, but as i said, i am fairly new to web programming and i still lack some of the fundamentals i think. I've looked around here, google, youtube etc but i can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Might be because i don't really know what i'm looking for :)

If anyone could help i would be ever grateful!

Thanks

Comment: You should not concern yourself with whats inside a library at all. If the provided library doesn't come with documentation or you suspect that it contains bugs, the best way to deal with it is to ask the author to fix the issues or if it is an open source project, fix the bug in the *source code* (not the minified one!) and open a pr.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :) I agree to a point - one of the alternatives is to actually ask the provider about this. But since this is a test of skill, i think i would do well to display som creativity and problem solving on my end. What makes me suspicious is that the API obviously works in some contexts (jsfiddle.net) but not in my VScode project... It makes me suspect i'm doing something wrong in my project...

Comment: In that case [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8245) might help.

Comment: Thank you my friend, that was of great help :) I managed to import the api.min.js file into the public index.html file and use it to extract data properly.

The question now is how i can reliably reach it from my react components in /src/... I'm guessing again that there is a very simple solution for this, but any chance you (or someone else) could point me in the right direction? Once again, i'm fairly new to web programming and there's still many things i don't know how to do intuitively... I'll look around in the meantime and see if i can come up with something.

Thanks again :)